# How to get array value in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

Trying to get value from array but no luck.

Array:

```
const int buf= 50;
const char* DAY1[buf] = {"A_7", "A_8", "A_9", "A_10", "A_1", "A_2", "A_3", "A_4", "A_5", "A_6", "J_1", "J_2"};
const char* DAY2[buf] = {"A_7", "A_8", "A_10", "A_1", "A_4", "A_5", "J_1", "J_2"};
```

Loop:

```
for (byte i = 1; i < (sizeof(DAY1) / sizeof(DAY1[0])); i++) {
    
          if( timeClient.getDay() == 0  ){   
              digitalWrite(DAY1[i-1], LOW);
              delay(DELAY);         
              digitalWrite(DAY1[i], HIGH);
              sprintf(statusBuf,"TEST = %s = %d = %ld", DAY1[i], i, ADelay.remaining() );
              sendLog(statusBuf);
          } else if( timeClient.getDay() == 1 ){  
              digitalWrite(DAY2[i-1], LOW);
              delay(DELAY);                    
              digitalWrite(DAY2[i], HIGH);
              sprintf(statusBuf,"TEST = %s = %d = %ld", DAY2[i], i, ADelay.remaining() );
              sendLog(statusBuf);
          } 
          
  }
```

Failed to compile - the error message:

***digitalWrite(DAY2[i-1], LOW);***

***invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' [-fpermissive]***

How to fix this?

Please help

Comment: `digitalWrite` accepts a byte, not a string. What are you trying to o?

Comment: You're trying to use strings as pin numbers.

Comment: I am trying to replace -  digitalWrite(A7, LOW)  -  with similar value from array  - digitalWrite(DAY1[i], LOW) - How to do this?

Comment: `"A_7"` is not similar to `A7`; the former is a string literal and the latter is an identifier that names an integer. I think you're looking for `int DAY1[buf] = { A7, A8, A9, ...};`

Comment: Sorry for my mistake - you are correct - int A_7 = 12 = the pin assignment  - char* DAY1[buf] = { A_7, A_8, ...} = the array - How to write digitalWrite(A_7, LOW) - with similar value from array digitalWrite(DAY1[i], LOW) ?

Answer (score 0):

Like moldbino writes, the `DAY1` and `DAY2` arrays shouldn't be using strings. The pin identifiers that you want should be in defined constants `A7`, `A8` etc.

Try declaring the arrays like:

```
const uint8_t DAY1[buf] = {A_7, A_8, A_9, A_10, ....
const uint8_t DAY2[buf] = {A_7, A_8, A_10, A_1, ....
```

Comment: Replace `const char* DAY1[buf]`  - with  - `const uint8_t DAY1[buf]`  - error message  =  `too many initializers for 'const uint8_t [50] {aka const unsigned char [50]}'`

Comment: @wieb Then there must be more than 50 elements in your initializer.

Comment: @molbdnilo  -  replace  `const int buf= 50;`  with  `const int buf= 500;`  -  now displaying different error message  `too many initializers for 'const uint8_t [500] {aka const unsigned char [500]}'`  on  `const uint8_t DAY2[buf] = {A_7, A_8, A_10, A_1, ....`

Comment: @wieb I think your actual code still uses string literals like `"A_7"`, which it shouldn't (as has been mentioned numerous times).

Comment: @molbdnilo - you are correct - replace it with `const uint8_t DAY1[buf] = {7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....`  then no error message anymore - thanks for the help and guidance